# Is there a mistake about @Inject in spring framework reference documentation 3.2.2?

Tags: spring

The documentation contains following paragraph.

"As with @Autowired, it is possible to use @Inject at the class-level, field-level, method-level and constructor-argument level."

If I have not a mistake, I know @Inject annotation can be used field-level, method-level and constructor-argument level, can not be used class-level.

Inject Annotation Source Code :

```
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Inject {}
```

Is it true?

Answer (score 2):

For me, they are almost equivalent, `@Inject` is part of the [CDI](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhb.html) introduced since Java EE 6 and `@Autowired` part of the Spring framework.

The `@Autowired` interface looks to have the same target as @Inject:

```
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD,METHOD})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Autowired
```

I think it is a small error in [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations) chapter 5.11.1 because I never seen any `@Autowired` annotation on a class level.

[This link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-standard-annotations-limitations) shows the difference and limitation of each approach.